# How can I provide a variable value to a lambda expression exactly once?

Tags: c#, lambda, polly

I'm trying to use the Polly library to monitor/restart tasks that fail. However, I'm having a difficult time keeping the same input arguments between retry attempts.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Polly;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sampler
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            // create and execute policies for each sampler
            List<Task> policy_list = new List<Task>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                var policy = Policy
                    .Handle<Exception>()
                    .RetryForeverAsync()
                    .ExecuteAsync(async () => await Program.TaskMethod(i.ToString()));

                policy_list.Add(policy);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(policy_list.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task TaskMethod(string task_id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Task {0}", task_id);
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("Hello from task {0}", task_id);

                int i = 0;
                int b = 32 / i;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
Starting Task 0
Starting Task 1
Hello from task 1
Hello from task 0
Starting Task 2 // BAD! this should be starting task 0
Starting Task 2 // BAD! this should be starting task 1
Hello from task 2
Hello from task 2
Starting Task 2
Starting Task 2
```

The obvious issue is associated with this line:`.ExecuteAsync(async () => await Program.TaskMethod(i.ToString()));` I am providing the task number as a variable which is a problem because this variable goes to "2" at the end of the for loop. Thus task ID 2 is used for the remainder of retries.

So my question: How would I reformat my lambda expression such that it only references the 'i' variable once such that it maintains its original task ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called closure. Safe `i` in a temporary local variable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    var policy = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .RetryForeverAsync()
        .ExecuteAsync(async () => await Program.TaskMethod(temp.ToString()));

    policy_list.Add(policy);
}
```

Here is a [nice article](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Closures) that explains it far better then I ever could in here.

Comment: "temporal"  Do you mean "temporary"?

Comment: lol thank you @Amy luckily weekend is not so far away anymore :D

Comment: This is a very simple solution that works... Do lambda expression simply save the environment (i.e. variables) required to invoke them? Thus you want to create a "one and done" environment variable call temp?

Comment: @Izzo in a way yes, but it captures the last value of the variable which is `2` in this case (value of `i` when the loop ends). I have the feeling that the creation `temp` in each iteration is forcing the system to store the value each time in a new memory location instead of overwriting the old one. Thus all values survive in the environment background. At least this is the explanation with which I calm myself :) but better read the article that I posted

Comment: Read the referenced article. Lambda capture variables in a closure, not values. In your original code, it is capturing `i` (and there is only one `i` variable). By the time the code runs, the value of `i` is 2. When you use the temp variable scoped to the loop, there is a new temp variable for each pass through the loop, and, the value doesn't change